# Increase line size in quiver3 plot matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I use `quiver3()` command in matlab and specify the points and its normals. i specify three points and corresponding 3 normals but when i plot in on an existing figure, the lines appear very small in size.

[image]

How to increase the line size? In [LineSpec](https://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/linespec.html), they only give line width option. i use the command like this:
    `quiver3(pts(:,1),pts(:,2),pts(:,3),n(:,1),n(:,2),n(:,3),'LineWidth',3,'color','g');`

`pts` and `n` are 3x3 matrices.

Comment: Which version of MATLAB is this? Consider tagging the question with either [`matlab-hg2`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/matlab-hg2/info) if appropriate.

Comment: @Dev-iL R2014b, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a solution in this link [line size in quiver 3](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94454-how-does-quiver-scale-the-vectors-it-plots). Setting the `'AutoScale'` property to `'off'` and adjusting your vector norm to control line size seems to be the solution.